# How to solve a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

I am using Vue on the front end and Laravel on the backend.  I am trying to access an api using "https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?sort=-data_date".  When I try to access the api I get the following error in my browser.
[image]

Here is my code in Vue

```
axios.get('https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?sort=-data_date',{
            }).catch( error => {
                var errors = error.response.data.errors
                console.log(errors);
            }).then(({ data }) => {
                console.log(data)
            });
```

I did some research and added

```
<httpProtocol>
           <customHeaders>
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
           </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

To my web.config file.  I also added the CORS extension to chrome and added the url.  Nothing I have done so far has helped.

Comment: do you own the service??? I mean, do you own transparecy.treasury.gov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

1) install CORS plugin on google chrome. It's an extension and could be found easily.

2) on api back-end, open .htaccess file at the root of the laravel directory and add these 4 lines.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "authorization,language,Content-Type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

in third-line authorization and language are my header parameters. you might have different ones.

I'd advise to simply install CORS. If you're in a development mode, simply install CORS on google chrome. If you choose the second option, these 4 lines could be only added for apache web server. For nginx, you have to add it somewhere else in nginx config. But I think you're in a development mode, so Install CORS.

Comment: Thanks, now I need to figure out Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: which option did you choose?

Comment: The second one.  I installed the chrome plugin, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Restart the chrome , then at the right on top you should turn it on.  there should be enable cross-origin resource sharing and make it turned on ,but also make sure when using chrome cors plugin, delete those lines I told you about .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem, while I develop my application i tested on Google Chrome but with --disabled-web-security flag in command line.

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```

Can someone approve or explain the side effects of this approach? As long as you don't play with your own sensitive data that's ok. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please install Cors provider and setup in order to add header in the request

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

this is my setting maybe helps you

```
'supportsCredentials' => true,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' =>  ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE','OPTIONS'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)